# Issue while using jQuery with Struts2 on Webspphere 6.1.0.0 - Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: xxx.action

Tags: jquery, struts2, websphere-6.1

I have a Struts2 application where I am using jQuery autoComplete feature. It is deployed on Websphere 6.1.0.0. Request is sent properly and response is received with valid results, but due to an error it is not displayed on page. Following is the Response I see in Console-->Response in Firebug.

```
{"4358":"002-004-45601234","4359":"009-004-45601234","4373":"011-123-456019098","4374":"011-123-45608756A"
}Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /ajax/autoComplete.action
```

This error is observed only on my machine. Application works in other environments without issues.

I have found a recommended solutions on [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24014758) and [this link too](http://frightanic.com/software-development/solution-to-error-404-srve0190e-on-websphere-6-1/), but it does not work for me.
I have tried running the server through Eclipse and outside of it too, but error remains. It happens on all browsers.

Any suggestions?